# Print Object tag contents in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, html-object

I have embedded a `pdf` with an `object` tag which is the only element in the body, as below...

```
<BODY>    
  <OBJECT id="ppdf" data="printpdf.pdf" width="100%" type="application/pdf" height="97%">
  </OBJECT> 
</BODY>
```

This loads in the browser correctly but when I go **File --> Print**, the pdf does not print!

I can add a button and onclick call `document.getElementById('ppdf').print();` but I am looking for a solution without having a button.

Is there a way to print the `pdf` that is in the `object` tag via the `IE9` browser print?